# Trying to use np.arange to create a counter that is half the length of my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm trying to fill a column in my pandas dataframe that is numbered from 1, and is a counter that goes up by one incrementally. However, I want it to be exactly half the length of the data already contained in the dataframe (for example, if my dataframe had 10 rows, I want the counter to go up to 5.) I've been playing around with different solutions, and currently I have this solution:

```
# Fill the cycles column with however many rows exist / 2
jac_output['Cycles'] = (np.arange(1,len(jac_output)+1))//2
```

However, rather than halfing the length of the dataframe, it merely duplicates numbers, like this:

```
print(jac_output['Cycles'].head(8))

0    0
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
7    4

print(jac_output['Cycles'].head(7))

0    0
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I feel this should be an easy solution but I'm tearing my hair out over it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use integer division by half of length of Dataframe by `//` for counter in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
jac_output = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(9)})

lens = len(jac_output)
arr = np.arange(lens)
a = arr // (lens // 2)
jac_output['Cycles'] = np.where(a == 0, arr + 1, np.nan)
print (jac_output)
   a  Cycles
0  0     1.0
1  1     2.0
2  2     3.0
3  3     4.0
4  4     NaN
5  5     NaN
6  6     NaN
7  7     NaN
8  8     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the counter to reproduce, one it reaches halfway through the length, I just want it to stop and finish?

Comment: @MurrayRoss - Unfortuantly not understand, what is expected ouput for `jac_output = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10)})` and for `jac_output = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(9)})` ?

Comment: Just `1 2 3 4 5 ` and `1 2 3 4 `

Comment: @MurrayRoss - and another values are `NaN`s in column?

Comment: Ideally I'd like them completely empty for space saving and performance

Comment: @MurrayRoss - `completely empty` in pandas not exist, there is used `NaN`s for missing values